# How to handle Done button click event for Samsung Galaxy Ace

Tags: android

I have created EditText attached `setOnKeyListener` and `addTextChangedListener` Using both of these I can get the text entered by the user using softkey. But If user press Done button of that soft key then I want to perform some action. I tried to handle with `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER`. But the keycode is not same. How to Handle Done button click  event for Samsung Galaxy Ace.

Comment: I have written some conditions wrong for which my code inside KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER did not get executed.

Answer (score 1):

If the keycodes are not the same, give this a try to figure out what the keycode actually is.

```
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        Log.d("KeyCode", keyCode);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Since KEYCODE_ENTER is just a constant that represents a number, if you can find out the number that corresponds to "Done" on the Samsung Galaxy, you can handle using that number (make sure it's not zero though.)

**Edit**:

Also: give this a try.

```
event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION)
```

FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION is used to identify keys with the autolabel "Done" so maybe if you handle using that instead of KEYCODE_ENTER, you'll get a positive result.